# Simulation of an asymetric half bridge not working

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, ltspice

I m not able to simulate an asymetric half brige circuit :( I m new on LTspice...

Here is the simulation which is really simple ...

[image]

When I simulate it, I am surprised to not have 400V across the inductor at least at the beginning of the turn on MOSFET... The two mosfets are synchrone. At least the gate signals are synchrone...

Thank you very much !

Comment: You are using the default settings for NMOS, which are not what you want. Use a model from the database, or a switch. Also see [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/419953/95619).

Comment: Sorry but this is confusing. You say you are not able to simulate it.... then you simulate it ..... and you are surprised at something and..... you give no real details or ask what might be obvious for this site..... a question.

Comment: Actually this is probably an error from me. I have to rework from my side ... The changement of MOSFET help me a lot !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple NMOS simulation error. High voltage drop across the nmos when trying to make a MOSFET switch](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/419953/simple-nmos-simulation-error-high-voltage-drop-across-the-nmos-when-trying-to-m)